# Sublime text replace pattern with regex

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

Using Sublime Text 3 I am trying to find all instances of a `<span>` element where the class value is not enclosed in quotes – e.g. `<span class=foo>` – and I want to wrap the class value in quotes.

The following is not working as expected as a search + replace with the regex option activated:

- Find what: `<span class=[A-Za-z0-9]*>`
- Replace with: `<span class="$1">`

The result I am getting (which I don't want) is `<span class="">`

Highlighting shows that the search term is correctly matching what I want but the **$1** part where I want to insert the previously captured pattern does not work. I have also tried `\1` in the replace pattern.

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Tell it what you want to (capture): `<span class=([A-Za-z0-9]*)>`

Comment: Be careful with whether you need to capture doublequotes as well.

Comment: @sp00m In this case there are no quotes in the existing text

Answer (score 1):

The answer was supplied as comment. The pattern to be captured was not wrapped in brackets.

> Tell it what you want to (capture): `<span class=([A-Za-z0-9]*)>`

- Alex K.